# ReactJS low re-rendering performance of the component

Tags: performance, react.js, jsx

First of all, for explaining the issue better and avoid pushing long code here, I'll post the links of the files from repository.

I have a feature simulation of the game that I am making a tools/wiki site for which you can see [here](https://enesceylan.github.io/mythic-tools/#/cube).

When you click on any cell inside the "cube" it display the **bonus** value of the clicked cell with a modal in mobile screens and in right side on the "cube" in desktop screens.

Each cube and each face starts with it's first (actually the 1st row and last element, so `CubeOfTruth[cubeIndex].faces[faceIndex].data[0][3]`) cell with the state of "**semi-active**" which sets the cells with dimmed and non colored backgrounds.

Cells can be in 3 states, "**inactive**", "**semi-active**" and "**active**".

"**inactive**" cells are disabled by default, they are not interactable until they become "**semi-active**".

When a "**semi-active**" (non colored frame and colored center cells) cell is clicked, that cells becomes "**active**", sets the adjacent cells "**semi-active**" and displays the bonus value it holds.

When a ""**active**" cell is clicked, it displays the "bonus" value it holds. No state change happens.

The entire system is held inside CubeOfTruth component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import './Cube.css';

import CubeOfTruthData from '../../data/cubeData';

import CubeContainer from './CubeContainer';

import CubeSelector from './CubeSelector';

import FaceSelector from './FaceSelector';

import CubeControls from './CubeControls';
import CubeModal from '../Modals/CubeModal';

function NonSeparatedCube({ setShowMenu }) {
  const [cubeIndex, setCubeIndex] = useState(0);
  const [faceIndex, setFaceIndex] = useState(0);
  const [cube, setCube] = useState(
    CubeOfTruthData[cubeIndex].faces[faceIndex].data
  );
  const [rowIndex, setRowIndex] = useState(0);
  const [cellIndex, setCellIndex] = useState(0);

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [disableModal, setDisableModal] = useState(false);
  const [bonus, setBonus] = useState('Hero Health +640');

  const isWideScreen = window.innerWidth >= 950;

  useEffect(() => {
    setCube(CubeOfTruthData[cubeIndex].faces[faceIndex].data);
    setBonus(CubeOfTruthData[cubeIndex].faces[faceIndex].data[0][3].bonus);
  }, [cubeIndex, faceIndex]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!isWideScreen && (
        <div className='system-container' onClick={() => setShowMenu(false)}>
          <CubeSelector setCubeIndex={setCubeIndex} />
          <CubeContainer
            cube={cube}
            setCube={setCube}
            setBonus={setBonus}
            setModal={setModal}
          />
          <div className='buttons-container'>
            <FaceSelector handleClick={(index) => setFaceIndex(index)} />
            <CubeControls
              cubeIndex={cubeIndex}
              faceIndex={faceIndex}
              cube={cube}
              setCube={setCube}
              disableModal={disableModal}
              setDisableModal={setDisableModal}
              isWideScreen={isWideScreen}
            />
          </div>
          {!disableModal && modal && (
            <CubeModal bonus={bonus} setModal={setModal} />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
      {isWideScreen && (
        <div className='system-container' onClick={() => setShowMenu(false)}>
          <CubeContainer
            cube={cube}
            setCube={setCube}
            setBonus={setBonus}
            setModal={setModal}
            isWideScreen={isWideScreen}
            setRowIndex={setRowIndex}
            setCellIndex={setCellIndex}
          />
          <section className='cube-interaction-container'>
            <CubeSelector setCubeIndex={setCubeIndex} />
            <div className='cube-bonus'>
              <p>{bonus}</p>
            </div>
            <div className='buttons-container'>
              <FaceSelector handleClick={(index) => setFaceIndex(index)} />
              <CubeControls
                cubeIndex={cubeIndex}
                faceIndex={faceIndex}
                cube={cube}
                setCube={setCube}
                disableModal={disableModal}
                setDisableModal={setDisableModal}
                isWideScreen={isWideScreen}
              />
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default NonSeparatedCube;
```

CubeContainer component, which renders each cell with the data I provided:

```
import CubeItem from './CubeItem';
import activateAdjacentCells from './functions/cell-functions/activateAdjacentCells';

function CubeContainer({
  cube,
  setCube,
  setBonus,
  setModal,
  isWideScreen,
  setRowIndex,
  setCellIndex,
}) {
  const handleCellClick = (id, row) => {
    let cubeClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cube));

    const item = cubeClone[row].find((item) => item.id === id);

    item.state = 'active';

    cubeClone = activateAdjacentCells(id, row, cubeClone, item);

    setCube(cubeClone);
    if (isWideScreen) {
      setRowIndex(row);
      setCellIndex(id % 4);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className='cube-wrapper'>
      <div id='cube-container'>
        {cube.map((row) => {
          return row.map((item) => {
            return (
              <CubeItem
                item={item}
                handleClick={handleCellClick}
                key={item.id}
                setBonus={setBonus}
                setModal={setModal}
                isWideScreen={isWideScreen}
              />
            );
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default CubeContainer;
```

CubeItem component (cells):

```
function CubeItem({ item, handleClick, setBonus, setModal, isWideScreen }) {
  const handleBgClass = (cellData) => {
    if (cellData.state === 'inactive') {
      return cellData.bg + '-inactive';
    } else if (cellData.state === 'semi-active') {
      return cellData.bg + '-semi-active';
    } else {
      return cellData.bg;
    }
  };

  return (
    <button
      className={`cell-item ${handleBgClass(item)}`}
      disabled={item.state === 'inactive' ? true : false}
      onClick={() => {
        handleClick(item.id, item.row);
        setBonus(item.bonus);
        setModal(!isWideScreen);
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default CubeItem;
```

When I click on each cell for the **first time** (setting a "**semi-active**" cell's state to "**active**" and setting the adjacent cell's "**inactive**" state to "**semi-active**"), that cell and the adjacent ones completely disappear and takes ~150ms (atleast that's what the performance tools say, even longer in mobile, sometimes doesn't even reappear if I don't click anywhere on screen) to reappear. I think I am re-rendering every single cell that didn't have a state change on every click which may be the cause of this image "flickering?".

How can I optimize this behaviour?